# How can I fully utilise the GPU when training my model in FloyHub?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nvidia, pytorch

I am training the below model on FloydHub using Jupyter Notebook. But, whenever I train the model it takes a lot of time(1 minute). The stats below the notebook displays that only 2% of the GPU is utilised.
I have tried running the command `torch.cuda.is_available()` and it returns `True`.

```
import torch
from torch import nn,optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets,transforms

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                               transforms.Normalize((0.5,0.5,0.5),(0.5,0.5,0.5)),
                               ])
trainset = datasets.MNIST('~/.pytorch/MNIST_data/',download=True,train=True,transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset,batch_size=64,shuffle=True)

testset = datasets.MNIST('~/.pytorch/MNIST_data/',download=True,train=False,transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset,batch_size=64,shuffle=True)

class Classifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.hidden = nn.Linear(784,256).cuda()
        self.output = nn.Linear(256,10).cuda()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.2).cuda()

    def forward(self,x):
        x = x.view(x.shape[0],-1).cuda()    
        x = self.hidden(x).cuda()
        x = torch.sigmoid(x).cuda()
        x = self.dropout(x).cuda()
        x = self.output(x).cuda()
        x = F.log_softmax(x,dim=1).cuda()
        return x.cuda()

model = Classifier()
model.cuda()
criterion = nn.NLLLoss().cuda()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=0.5)

epochs = 30
training_losses = []
test_losses = []


for e in range(epochs):
    train_loss = 0
    test_loss = 0
    accuracy = 0
    for images,labels in trainloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(images)
        labels = labels.cuda()
        loss = criterion(output,labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss+=loss.item()

    with torch.no_grad():
        # set the model to testing mode
        model.eval()
        for images,labels in testloader:
            output = model(images)
            labels = labels.cuda()
            test_loss+=criterion(output,labels)
            ps = torch.exp(output)
            # get the class with the highest probability
            _,top_class = ps.topk(1,dim=1)
            equals = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)
            accuracy+=torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor))

    model.train()

    training_losses.append(train_loss/len(trainloader))
    test_losses.append(test_loss/len(testloader))

    if((e+1)%5 == 0):
        print(f"Epoch:{e+1}\n",
                f"Training Loss:{train_loss/len(trainloader)}\n",
                f"Test Loss:{test_loss/len(testloader)}\n",
                f"Test Accuracy:{(accuracy/len(testloader)*100)}\n\n")
```

Comment: I'm surprised your code even works, considering everything is on GPU, except the input itself (notice you're never calling `images .cuda()`)

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions based on use of MNIST (small dataset):
- pre load your data: i.e. don't use the standard `dataloader`, but pre-load to `.to(cuda)`, and iterate on this.
- increase your batch size.
- don't use MLPs (linear layers), try CNNs instead.

Comment: Does Pytorch automatically chooses not to fully utilise the GPU because MNIST is a small dataset ?

Comment: No not quite, rather _it doesn't automatically pre-load data into GPU memory_ . So if your dataset is small enough, you should do this manually.